# I would like to use a library in my NUXT application, but it is giving me error that Top-level await is not available in the configured target env

Tags: nuxt.js, vue-composition-api, nuxtjs3

I am importing a npm library inside my component and inside

error in that npm library:
Top-level await is not available in the configured target environment ("chrome87", "edge88", "es2020", "firefox78", "safari14" + 2 overrides)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ikpYs.png)

That library is working but I would like to remove all those top level await errors from it.

Comment: Did you add `nitro` of `esbuild` inside your `nuxt.config.ts` file?

Comment: Yes and also changed build target using that but still getting this error